# which browser to start with? IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari?

Tags: browser, cross-browser

We all know the difference rendering on different browsers and various support for styles and other things on different browsers.

While start developing a site, which browser would be optimal to start and then to proceed with convincing other browsers by various methods.

For e.g. Is it ok to start with IE and then do the necessary changes to display the same in FF and chrome etc? Else start with modern/webkit browsers and then degrade the code according to IE and other low versions.

Also, I would like to know which browsers we can avoid. Many sites have stopped support to IE6. So, as developers we can also start avoiding some sites? If yes, what are all? (which versions of what broswers)

Comment: I like to think of a web browser as simply a tool that keep in tool box.  Unfortunately many people opt to only use one type of browser.  For some it's because they don't know or want to get another tool.  There are also those that have a certain amount of religious vigor to only using certain browsers.
So, with that said, another way to ask your question is:  Am I comfortable with alienating a certain percentage of my potential customer base.  If so, how much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to do is ensure you are developing your HTML and CSS to be as standards compliant as possible. This will ease cross browser testing later.

I develop everything on a modern browser, typically Firefox because it has many useful tools to help me. After each stage is working fine in FF, I load up Chrome, Safari and Opera, which 9 times out of 10 render just fine.

Then it's off to IE land. I start with the latest IE build, then work my way back to 6.
Then I spent the next week swearing and tweaking all of the IE6 problems until it works as well as it can.

Comment: Nice. Thats a nice hierarchy to go with. FF->Ch->Saf->IE--; Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, Also don't forget Opera, it's market share is quite low but it's always good to be certain. Plus it's used in a lot of mobile devices these days.

Answer (score 1):

I always used to start with firefox, as it was quite unforgiving to mistakes, and most things that rendered correctly on it rendered correctly on IE. The other way around was not so.

IE used to be easy to work with, because it was so forgiving. This however meant that when testing on firefox and other browsers, nothing worked and I had to rework lots of code.

Comment: That's true. IE is flexible sometimes when others not.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start with the worst or the most popular. You are lucky: the worst and the most popular one is the same. Internet Explorer.

Comment: The problem with primary testing in IE is that you will most likely build a site that relies on the rendering errors in IE, and it will look totally whacked when you view it in a browser that renders the code correctly...

Comment: Jonathan: for me it means doing the most difficult tasks fist, always.

Comment: Guffa: Just checked and IE is not the most used browser anymore. Firefox is. So I totally agree.

Comment: Pierre, You were right about doing the hard thing first. Even I did this recently. http://twitter.com/2sks/status/16302833482

However, as Guffa said, it was very weird when i checked with FF. The answer by Neil seems good. What you say? Because if you start with IE6 your scope is very limited. If you start with recent version of chrome you have plenty of choices to go with. i.e. You may use HTML5 and CSS3 in the highest and replace the same with alternatives in the lower version. But we cannot do the same vice versa!

Comment: Neil's proposal is very good. I used to develop on Firefox first too because of the nice developer's tools available. Chrome is very good for that too.

But few years ago, IE was the top used browser, which is not the case anymore, so please ignore my answer. Neil's answer should be the one that you should accepted.